# How to assign a bold(style) for a variable using ES6 string template in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template

I need to assign for my variable in ES6 string template a style[bold].

My code looks:

Component

```
export class AppComponent {
  public keyword = '';
  public text = '';
  onKey(value) {
    this.keyword = value;
    this.text = `Search for ${this.keyword} with`;
  };
}
```

Template

```
<input #box class="search-for" type="text" (keyup)="onKey(box.value)">

  <p *ngIf="keyword " class="search-line ">{{ text }}</p>
```

For example, if user types “Angular” then the text will be “Search for **Angular** with:”

Thank you.

Comment: im not an angular expert, but cant you simply include html into the string? this.text = "Search for <h1>${this.keyword}</h1> with";

Comment: @Jonasw thank you, it's very cool and simple idea. thx. Anyway, i have a lot ways to solute this. First idea was with es5 string template, and i interested in solve this problem. But thank you)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ngModel` and `Input`, that's what you need. Try this code:

```
import { Input } from '@angular/core';

export class AppComponent {
  @Input() keyword: string;
}

<input class="search-for" type="text" [(ngModel)]="keyword">

<p *ngIf="keyword" class="search-line ">Search for <b>{{keyword}}</b> with:</p>
```

Comment: Thank, anyway, it's simple solution and it's pretty good. But i don't understand for what @Input() this ;))) But okay.

Comment: You can read about directives [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html#!#bindings) and if my answer is what you were looking for, then check it as answer.

Comment: but your code works without @Input() :))) All happens in one component ;) And tip for you - you should to use name=".." when using [(ngModel)]=".."

Comment: That's not necessary to specify `name` attribute. But if you want to use that in form and send data through it, then yes, `name` is needed.